# read file into a dictionary so that columns become keys and values, Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a data file in the following format:

```
 9, 12, 16, ABC, a12d
 8, 09, 24, ADP, v154a
 6, 07, 16, ADP, l28a
 2, 14, 15, CDE, d123p
```

I need to build a dictionary of sets in the following format:

```
 ABC : ([a12d])
 ADP : ([v154a, l128a])
 CDE : ([d123p])
```

I can build a set of any of the columns eg:

```
with open('data.csv','r') as r:
    name = set([line.strip().split(',')[3] for line in r])
```

I figure there must be a way to make every element in the set into a dictionary key and its adjacent value add to a set? There is an added complication that some of the keys have a multiple values (for example lines 2 and 3 above) but they are separated with into separate lines.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)

with open('data.csv','r') as r:
    for line in r:
        splitted = line.strip().split(',')
        name = splitted[3].strip()
        value = splitted[4].strip()
        d[name].add(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None, usecols=[3,4], index_col=0, skipinitialspace=1, names=["key", "value"])
```

Which can be read as read `data.csv`, which contain no `header`, use only columns `3` and `4`, and use column `0` (formerly `3`) as the index. `Skip the initial space` in the values, and `name` the column you read (`3` and `4`) `key` and `value`. This will give you:

```
df 
     value
key       
ABC   a12d
ADP  v154a
ADP   l28a
CDE  d123p
```

So you can access any value with `.loc`:

```
df.loc["ABC"].values
array(['a12d'], dtype=object)

df.loc["ADP"].values
array([['v154a'],
       ['l28a']], dtype=object)
```

For the latter, you can flatten the array with `ravel()`:

```
df.loc["ADP"].values.ravel()
array(['v154a', 'l28a'], dtype=object)
```

So it's not really a dictionary, but it behaves a bit like it, and you can do much more with this kind of object (a `pandas Dataframe`). Plus you can easily read and write csv files.
If you don't know pandas, have a look :

- http://pandas.pydata.org/
- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the below code to read column values and then convert them to the dictionary in python

```
cat dictionary.txt (This txt has info about Name Age Birthyear)
Luffy    20    2000
Nami     18    2002
Chopper  10    

##################### code is here #######
#!/usr/bin/python3.7.4

d = {} 
with open("dictionary.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line=line.split()
        d.setdefault(line[0],[]).append(line[1])
        if len(line)==3:
           d.setdefault(line[0],[]).append(line[2])
        else:
           d.setdefault(line[0],[]).append('NULL') 
print(d)
```

**Output:**
{'Luffy': ['20', '2000'], 'Nami': ['18', '2002'], 'Chopper': ['10', 'NULL']}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].